# Error while loading shared library libx264.so.155 :Permission denied

Tags: ffmpeg, shared-library, audacity

While starting softwares such ffmpeg and audacity, I am getting `error while loading shared libraries: libx264.so.152: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied` . I am using Ubuntu18.4.
Can anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try reinstalling the [package which contains the `libx264.so.152` library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libx264.so.152):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libx264-152
```

and then retry to run `ffmpeg` or `audacity`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't works.